# Use specific docker shared runner for Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

We have a few shared runners that have the same tag 'docker', some of them fail the job but some succeed, is it possible to select a specific runner using its ID?

Answer (score 0):

Runners can have many tags. You can create a unique tag for each of your runners in addition to the `docker` tag.

For example, you might use a hostname, IP address, or similar as a tag.

Comment: problem is i dont have access to the runners, maintained by another team, was looking for a quick solution that doesnt require their intervention.

Comment: @AlaAbid unfortunately, tags are the only way to select runners specific runners out of the shared pool.